# How to override built-in command in xonsh?

Tags: python, shell, xonsh

I'm trying to override 'ls' command to display dotfiles in "dotfiles" directory.

Here is my code.

```py
def _ls():
    if $(pwd).rstrip(os.linesep) == $DOTFILES:
        ls -Ga
    else:
        ls -G
aliases['ls'] = _ls
```

This code goes into an endless loop because `_ls` function calls `ls` command and it calls `_ls` function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinite alias call shouldn't happen -- would you mind opening up an issue at github.com/xonsh/xonsh/issues?

In the interim, here's a way to structure your alias that will work without any fixes:

```
def _ls(args):
    args = args[0].replace('-', '') if args else ''
    if $(pwd).rstrip(os.linesep) == $DOTFILES:
        $(which -s ls) @(f"-{''.join(set(args + 'aG'))}")
    else:
        $(which -s ls) @(f"-{''.join(set(args + 'G'))}")
aliases['ls'] = _ls
```

The `-s` argument to `which` skips alias resolution, so that returns the path to the actual `ls` executable. Then the `set` logic is to make sure arguments aren't duplicated (although I'm not sure that's strictly necessary).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I don't mind open issue.